# Mixing virtual and templates

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I know there are some some pitfalls when mixing inheritance and templates, but I'd like to know if the code below (which compiles and seems to run well) is "legal" and wellformed.

```
struct ISession {
    virtual ~ISession() = deafult;
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

template <typename Derived>
struct SessionBase : public ISession {
    SessionBase() {
        static_assert(is_base_of_v<SessionBase<Derived>, Derived>);
    }

    void run() override {
        derived().connect();
    }
    
    Derived& derived() {
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
};

struct PlainSession : public SessionBase<PlainSession> {
    void connect() {
        // do connect plain
    }
};

struct SslSession : public SessionBase<SslSession> {
    void connect() {
        // do connect ssl
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    list<unique_ptr<ISession>> sessions;
    sessions.emplace_back(make_unique<PlainSession>());
    sessions.emplace_back(make_unique<SslSession>());
    for_each(sessions.begin(), sessions.end(), [](auto& session) { session->run(); });
}
```

Comment: what pitfalls do you refer to? Why do you think the code could be problematic? You could replace `SessionBase<SslSession>` with a hypothetical `SessionBase_SslSession` and the effect would be more or less the same

Comment: This is an application of the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp) and at first glance your code seems fine. I would just recommend adding a `static_assert` like `static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<SessionBase<Derived>, Derived>);` to make sure someone doesn't try to use `SessionBase` incorrectly. Edit : I'd also consider making `SessionBase` abstract.

Comment: François, thanks for the answer and advise !

Answer (score 1):

The "pitfall" is that you cannot have a member template that is also  virtual. That would result in an unknown number of virtual functions, potentially growing for each new use of the class.

```
template<typename T>
virtual void use(T);   // not possible
```

As long as it is *either* a template or virtual, but not both, it is ok.